# How to define Nested enum type in GraphQL schema

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I have an enum defined in graphql schema as below:

```
enum QueryType {
    NORMAL, RANGE, REGEX, WILDCARD
}
```

But the WILDCARD query, can be further specified as STARTSWITH, ENDSWITH and CONTAINS,

So can we achieve something like below while defining Schema

```
 enum QueryType {
        NORMAL, RANGE, REGEX, enum WILDCARD { STARTSWITH, ENDSWITH, CONTAINS}
    }
```

or

```
 enum QueryType {
            NORMAL, RANGE, REGEX, WILDCARD: WildCardType
        }
   enum WildCardType { STARTSWITH, ENDSWITH, CONTAINS}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such nested enums in GraphQL schema. You can consider to model it using two separate fields with separate enums .

```
enum QueryType {
    NORMAL ,RANGE , REGEX , WILDCARD
}

enum WildcardType {
    STARTSWITH , ENDSWITH ,CONTAINS
}
```

And suppose an object type call `SearchQuery` need to contains these info . Its schema may look likes:

```
type SearchQuery {
    queryType : QueryType!
    wildcardType : WildcardType
}
```

`wildcardType` is an optional field which only contains the value if the queryType is `WILDCARD`. Otherwise , it should be null.

Alternatively you can also consider to model it to be more 'polymorphism' style using the [interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces). Something likes :

```
interface SearchQuery {
  queryType: QueryType!
}

type WildCardQuery implements  SearchQuery {
    queryType: QueryType!
    wildcardType : WildcardType!
}

type NonWildCardQuery implements SearchQuery{
    queryType: QueryType!
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KenChan, how can I convert this type to input type, as I can't use the type WildCardQuery and type NonWildCardQuery as input type for a field?

Comment: The input type does not support interface. I am afraid that you have to use the first option for the input type at this moment though there are in-progress RFC of @oneof (https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825) to achieve the 'polymorphism' style of the input